# Want to get base64 data from a file URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I want to get base64 data and i have a url which will be give me the file.
I have tried the below mentioned way to get base64 data from URL
I have made a ajax call to the the given URL

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: DownloadUrl,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            if (data){

            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, statusText, errorThrown) {
            console.log(statusText);
        }
});
```

In the success event, i am getting some decoded data, I have encoded that using "window.btoa". But now my file is getting corrupted after this way.

Is this the right way to get base64 data?

Any other Way to get this data?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call `encodeURIComponent` on the returned data?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: DownloadUrl,
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (data) {
      data = btoa(encodeURIComponent(data));
    }
  },
  error: function (xhr, statusText, errorThrown) {
    console.log(statusText);
  }
});
```